# Good c++ lib for threading

Tags: c++, multithreading

I prefer a lib solely based on pthreads. What is a good c++ lib to for threading?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I looked at some options some time ago. Here are some:

- [Boost Thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) - This is the most standard choice. Boost is the most standard library for C++, that is not in the official standard.
- [POCO](http://pocoproject.org/) - Has thread support and a lot more. Is my preferred choice because it lets  you set thread priorities, something boost doesn't support. Thread priorities are important for my application domain (soft real-time).
- [Zthread](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zthread) - Looks a good library. I have no experience with it.
- [ACE](http://www.cs.wustl.edu/~schmidt/ACE.html) - Well known library. I have no experience with it.

Then you have libraries that let you operate at an higher abstraction level like [Thread Buildings Blocks](http://www.intel.com/cd/software/products/asmo-na/eng/294797.htm).

Answer (score 12):

How about [boost threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html)?

> Boost.Thread enables the use of
>   multiple threads of execution with
>   shared data in portable C++ code. It
>   provides classes and functions for
>   managing the threads themselves, along
>   with others for synchronizing data
>   between the threads or providing
>   separate copies of data specific to
>   individual threads.

Answer (score 1):

- [Boost Threads](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) seems a pretty obvious suggestion.
- Also if you need some concurrency, but don't want to play that much with the threads, than maybe [Futures](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2008/n2671.html) (see also Boost mailing lists)?

Answer (score 1):

Also, also, if you need some concurrency, but don't want to play that much with the threads, then you could look at [Thread Building Blocks](http://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/).