# Why the std::this_thread namespace?

Tags: c++, c++11, library-design

Is there a technical reason for the std::this_thread namespace? Why could the members of this namespace not have been implemented as static members of the std::thread class?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From [the original proposal](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2184.html), the way to get a `thread::id` is spelled `get_id()` whether you are getting the `thread::id` for yourself, or for a child thread:

> Note the use of the `this_thread` namespace to disambiguate when you are
>   requesting the id for the current thread, vs the id of a child thread.
>   The `get_id` name for this action remains the same in the interest of
>   reducing the conceptual footprint of the interface.

```
std::thread my_child_thread(f);
typedef std::thread::id ID;

ID my_id = std::this_thread::get_id();  // The current thread's id
ID your_id = my_child_thread.get_id();  // The child   thread's id
```

Thus the `this_thread` namespace is a readable way to differentiate between the two, while keeping the conceptual interface to a minimum (same name for getting a thread id).

Here's a possible alternative design:

```
struct thread
{
    static int get_id() {return 1;}
    int get_id() const {return 2;}
};
```

One disadvantage of this design is that it does not compile:

```
test.cpp:4:9: error: static and non-static member functions with the same parameter types cannot be overloaded
    int get_id() const {return 2;}
        ^
test.cpp:3:16: note: previous declaration is here
    static int get_id() {return 1;}
               ^
1 error generated.
```

Another design would have given the static member a different name.  But now the interface is bigger. The original proposal also treated another function the exact same way:

```
bool have_i_been_canceled = std::this_thread::cancellation_requested();  // Current thread's cancellation status
bool have_you_been_canceled = my_child_thread.cancellation_requested();  // Child   thread's cancellation status
```

Thus it made a lot of sense to reuse the names so clients don't have to learn so many names. They just need to learn to use the `this_thread` namespace if they want to query the current thread. Unfortunately the committee removed thread cancellation during standardization.

Comment: Thanks, but how could my_child_thread.get_id()  ever be ambiguous? I guess I am looking for a real-life example here. Which I know is  a lot to ask.

Comment: @user2100815 Well, not so much ambiguous as "not working". If `get_id` is the `static` member function to get the current thread's ID, `my_child_thread.get_id()` calls that static member function. See http://codepad.org/JRTvzDLk for a simplified example. (By the way, I didn't come up with this myself, someone has written this in a comment an hour ago!)

Comment: @user2100815 give us an example of how else you would do it.

Comment: @Seth You seem to think I am criticising the standard library. On the contrary, I'm trying to understand it.

Comment: @user2100815 I know you are, and if you think I'm criticising you, you are mistaken. I am trying to understand it too. I'm just offering my opinion, which is worth less than the bytes it's encoded in, that's all. When I asked for an example from you, I wanted one because you asked how it could be ambiguous, which it can't be unless you decide to do it another way.