# qpThreads documentation

Tags: c++, documentation

Is there any documentation on qpThreads?  In what way is it different from pthreads?

Comment: can you elaborate why you want to use exactly this particular library? It may help to get better answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found some documentation finally.

[Sourceforge qpthreads](http://sourceforge.net/docman/display_doc.php?docid=21185&group_id=100112)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like [qpthread](http://sourceforge.net/projects/qpthread/) has become a sourceforge project. It hasn't changed in four or five years from the CVS repository and doesn't seem to contain any documentation. Chances are that if you don't have docs on it, then none exist save for the source code and headers of course.

I grabbed the source out of curiosity and it looks like a pretty standard threading implementation that is layered over pthreads. The largest difference is that pthreads is a C-style interface and qpThreads is an OO interface more akin to what you might find in Java. I haven't delved into it very deeply, but you might want to look at the interfaces like [java.util.Timer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html). Some of the interfaces look quite similar to what qpThreads offers.

You might want to investigate replacing it with [Boost.thread](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/doc/html/thread.html) or something more recent. Chances are that you will have better luck maintaining it. It shouldn't be that hard to do depending on how much code you have to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

From a cursory look at google search results, qpThreads seems to be an obscure C++ threading class library.  pthreads is a very widely used, POSIX-compliant, multi-platform threading C API.

Comment: Google was of no help :(.  It's unfortunate that my organization uses this obscure library.

Answer (score 0):

The most important thing about using libraries is making sure they are actively maintained.
You should use a well known and heavily used library if possible. This way you will also have a vast number of people to ask questions if you have any.

Please see this similar SO question for more details:
[Good c++ lib for threading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/596360/good-c-lib-for-threading) (or use the search box for more).